Is the nightmare clown a human, doppelganger, or something else?
There's an evil clown that appears at the end of nightmare mode who will ask to play a game.
If you say no, he stays until you call DDD and kills the DDD agent. If you say yes and subsequently lose his game he kills you. If you beat his game, he'll let you go and you beat nightmare mode.
Is the clown a human, doppelganger or something else?

No, I don't think the nightmare clown is a human or doppelganger.
While there may not be official developer statements confirming the clown’s nature - in my view - the game’s narrative suggests that the clown is a supernatural presence rather than a human, doppelganger or anything else.
